# Problema no SERVIDOR - perdi o meu repositorio

Tags: git

Peço ajuda pois nao entendo muito de GIT e tenho medo de causar problemas maiorias

Eu tinha um repositorio git em um servidor, cujo o nome era Projeto.git
Controlava o mesmo por versoes, cada branch pra cada versao do meu projeto

Entao tinha a MASTER, VERSAO_1,2 e 3.
No momento na pasta do projeto, estava no checkout da VERSAO3.

DEU PROBLEMA E PERDI O arquivo "projeto.git" no meu servidor, ficando impossibilitado de fazer pushs.

COMO EU FACO AGORA PRA CRIAR UM NOVO "PROJETO.GIT" no servidor, sem que eu perca meu historico de alteracoes?

Nao ligo pra perder o historico de branchs, eu posso pegar a branch que eu estou (VERSAO3) e torna-la master. Mas tenho que manter o historico de alteracoes etc.

Se puderem me ajudar agradeco
Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Você tinha dado algum `git clone`, `git fetch` ou coisa assim no seu repositório local?

Comment: dei o git clone há varios meses atras, desde entao só uso o git push mesmo pra ir mandando as alteracoes pro servidor.

Nao dei nenhum git fetch nao.
Só quem mexe nesse repositorio sou eu.

Creio que na hora de dar algum push caiu a conexao e depois alguns arquivos ficaram corrompidos no servidor

Answer (score 0):

No git não se perde nada! Se você tinha esse arquivo no servidor, e agora não tem mais, alguém deletou, você não está conseguindo fazer o push por que os repositórios estão inconsistentes!

Algumas ações que você pode fazer:

1. Pesquisar se o arquivo realmente foi deletado no servidor... Se você não tiver uma ferramenta "online" para visualizar os repositórios, clone o repositório e veja o histórico. Em seguida você pode desfazer esse commit, e regularizar o repositório.
2. Você pode forçar a reescrita do repositório no servidor, baseada no seu repositório que você considera correto! User um *push -force*. Fazendo isso você terá que pedir aos dev's para clonarem o repositório novamente (maneira mais fácil).